# Spark SQL reading parquet tables and csv tables differently

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cost-based-optimizer

I have two external tables created in the spark-sql. One has a file format of `parquet` and other one has file format as `textfile`.

When we extract query plan on these two table, spark treats the two tables differently.

The output of query plan on parquet table is:

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [*]
+- 'Filter ('country = Korea)
   +- 'UnresolvedRelation `test_p`

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
Address: string, Age: string, CustomerID: string, CustomerName: string, CustomerSuffix: string, Location: string, Mobile: string, Occupation: string, Salary: string, Country: string
Project [Address#0, Age#1, CustomerID#2, CustomerName#3, CustomerSuffix#4, Location#5, Mobile#6, Occupation#7, Salary#8, Country#9]
+- Filter (country#9 = Korea)
   +- SubqueryAlias test_p
      +- Relation[Address#0,Age#1,CustomerID#2,CustomerName#3,CustomerSuffix#4,Location#5,Mobile#6,Occupation#7,Salary#8,Country#9] parquet

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Project [Address#0, Age#1, CustomerID#2, CustomerName#3, CustomerSuffix#4, Location#5, Mobile#6, Occupation#7, Salary#8, Country#9], Statistics(sizeInBytes=2.2 KB, hints=none)
+- Filter (isnotnull(country#9) && (country#9 = Korea)), Statistics(sizeInBytes=2.2 KB, hints=none)
   +- Relation[Address#0,Age#1,CustomerID#2,CustomerName#3,CustomerSuffix#4,Location#5,Mobile#6,Occupation#7,Salary#8,Country#9] parquet, Statistics(sizeInBytes=2.2 KB, hints=none)

== Physical Plan ==
*FileScan parquet default.test_p[Address#0,Age#1,CustomerID#2,CustomerName#3,CustomerSuffix#4,Location#5,Mobile#6,Occupation#7,Salary#8,Country#9] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: PrunedInMemoryFileIndex[file:/C:/dev/tests2/Country=Korea], PartitionCount: 1, PartitionFilters: [isnotnull(Country#9), (Country#9 = Korea)], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<Address:string,Age:string,CustomerID:string,CustomerName:string,CustomerSuffix:string,Loca...
```

The output of query plan on csv table is:

```
 == Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Project [*]
+- 'Filter ('country = Korea)
   +- 'UnresolvedRelation `test_p3`

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
Address: string, Age: string, CustomerID: string, CustomerName: string, CustomerSuffix: string, Location: string, Mobile: string, Occupation: string, Salary: string, Country: string
Project [Address#0, Age#1, CustomerID#2, CustomerName#3, CustomerSuffix#4, Location#5, Mobile#6, Occupation#7, Salary#8, Country#9]
+- Filter (country#9 = Korea)
   +- SubqueryAlias test_p3
      +- HiveTableRelation `default`.`test_p3`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [Address#0, Age#1, CustomerID#2, CustomerName#3, CustomerSuffix#4, Location#5, Mobile#6, Occupation#7, Salary#8], [Country#9]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Filter (isnotnull(country#9) && (country#9 = Korea)), Statistics(sizeInBytes=1134.0 B, rowCount=3, hints=none)
+- HiveTableRelation `default`.`test_p3`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [Address#0, Age#1, CustomerID#2, CustomerName#3, CustomerSuffix#4, Location#5, Mobile#6, Occupation#7, Salary#8], [Country#9], Statistics(sizeInBytes=9.6 KB, rowCount=128, hints=none)

== Physical Plan ==
HiveTableScan [Address#0, Age#1, CustomerID#2, CustomerName#3, CustomerSuffix#4, Location#5, Mobile#6, Occupation#7, Salary#8, Country#9], HiveTableRelation `default`.`test_p3`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe, [Address#0, Age#1, CustomerID#2, CustomerName#3, CustomerSuffix#4, Location#5, Mobile#6, Occupation#7, Salary#8], [Country#9], [isnotnull(country#9), (country#9 = Korea)]
```

Why is the difference so?
Spark version : 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Logically it does not treat them differently.

But they have different internal formats, parquet is columnar optimized, hence a different approach can apply. E.g. pruning in PARQUET.